# Como eu faço para uma programa escrito em python abrir com dois click's feito um executavel?

Tags: python, script

Um exemplo:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding: utf-8

# window.py

from gi.repository import Gtk

class App(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Gtk.Window, self).__init__(title='Hello World')
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.set_size_request(600, 400)
        self.set_keep_above(True)
        self.set_modal(True)
        self.set_icon_name('Hello World')
        self.set_deletable(True)
        self.set_opacity(1)
        self.set_skip_pager_hint(True)
        self.set_skip_taskbar_hint(False)
        self.set_auto_startup_notification(False)
        self.set_border_width(10)

main = App()
main.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
main.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Como é que eu faço para abrir essa meu script dando dois click feito um executavel?

Comment: Qual Sistema operativo? se for windows , podes começar por criar um .bat file

Comment: bom eu quero criar de preferencia mutiplataforma mas se voce souber alguma receita para windows pode dizer @psantos

Comment: vÊ a minha resposta

Comment: to esperando o windows inicializar pra eu testar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para Windows, Cria uma .bat file com um conteúdo parecido com este:

```
@echo off
python c:\teu_script.py %*
pause
```

Tens que ter o python instalado e o comando `python` reconhecido.

Ou podes criar o executável a partir do PyInstaller (http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

No linux, podes adicionar o "shebang" no início do seu script python que automaticamente será reconhecido como um programa python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

É necessário tornar o mesmo script executável com o seguinte comando:

> chmod +x seu_script_python.py

Comment: eu testei o pyintaller aqui funcionou, mas quando eu coloquei o executavel na minha area de trabalho não pegou mais, esse programa so faz um englomention eu não recomendo, vou ter que fazer trabalho sujo de qualquer forma setar aonde cada arquivo vai ser instalado e deixar o python executar o script é o jeito mas valeu pela a ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Use [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org). Isso tornará seu Python em um `.exe`. As opções são:

```
pyinstaller --onefile < tranforma ele em um arquivo só
            --noconsole < desabilita o console
            --icon < coloca um icon no seu .exe
```

Você pode executar, por exemplo:

```
pyinstaller --onefile teste.py --noconsole

pip install pyinstaller
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizo o cx_freeze, este programa cria o o arquivo executável, porém ao criar o arquivo o mesmo vem acompanhado de outros arquivos necessários na hora da execução, ou seja é criada uma pasta com um arquivo dll + o executável. Infelizmente não consegui juntar todos os arquivos criados em um só.

Espero ter ajudado.